# Printing concentric squares of numbers

Tags: c, ascii-art

I wrote a code which prints the following pattern :

```
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5
5 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 2 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 2 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 
5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

The code is as follows :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
   int n,i,k,b,a;
   printf("ENTER OUTER NUMBER:");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   for(i=0;i<2*n-1;i++){
     printf("%d",n);
   }
   printf("\n");
   int p=n;
   for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
     int a=0;
     for(k=0;k<=i;k++){
        printf("%d",n-a);
        a++;
     }
     for(b=0;b>i;b++){
        printf(" ");
     } 
     for(k=1;k<=2*p-3;k++){
        printf("%d",n-i-1);
     }  
     p--;
     for(k=i;k>=0;k--){
        printf("%d",n-k);
     }
     printf("\n");
   }
    int q=1;
    for(i=0;i<n-2;i++){
     for(k=n;k>i+1;k--){
        printf("%d",k);
     }
     for(k=1;k<=2*q-1;k++){
        printf("%d",q+1);
     }
     q++;
     for(k=2+i;k<=n;k++){
        printf("%d",k);
     }
     printf("\n");
   }
   for(i=0;i<2*n-1;i++){
     printf("%d",n);
   }
   getchar();
}
```

I printed the first and last line independently.Then,I divided the pattern into two halves and considered some common triangular patterns as follows:

```
5                 5    2 3 4 5 
5 4             4 5      3 4 5
5 4 3         3 4 5        4 5
5 4 3 2     2 3 4 5          5
```

The code ran well in the **CODE BLOCKS** IDE.But, I think it's too long and I complicated the coding.My query is:

1. Can I shorten the code with the similar logic of breaking the pattern into parts or mine is ok ?
2. Is there any alternative to this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use a bit more spaces. It will make your code more readable.
- Try to be coherent with your indents
- You should sanitize input. What happen if user enter a number greater than 9 ? Or 0, 1, or 2? Or negative number? Or not a number? Never trust user, They all try to broke your program.
- When you just print on char, prefer `putchar()` instead of `printf()`.

Here's my solution, *maybe* not the most optimal, but clean and short. I compute the distance from the current coordinate to nearest side and then remove it to the base number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int n = 5;
    int a;
    int b;
    const int m = 2*n-1;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            a = (i >= n) ? m - i - 1: i;
            b = (j >= n) ? m - j - 1 : j;
            putchar('0' + n - ((a < b) ? a : b));
        }     
        putchar ('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To improve this, you could split the inner loop to avoid the two conditional assignments. I let you trying to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The same pattern can be produced by a single instance of nested for loops, where outer loop variable is line and inner one - horizontal position.

I do not want to spoil your fun in finding the function at the heart of the loop (at least yet), which given two coordinates produces the value at those coordinates.

Comment: Did you speak about the method as mentioned in the abovw answer?

Comment: Yes. The method above is that.